# How to replace dmenu with fzf as application launcher in suckless dwm

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, dwm

I am using dwm with dmenu but am trying to replace dmenu for fzf as an application launcher. I have looked at [examples](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Examples#fzf-as-dmenu-replacement) in fzf wiki but did not find information about a particular problem.

The problem is that I can not start PhpStorm with the setup shown in the example. So I came up with partial and incomplete solution probably due to lack of knowledge of Linux.

Here is my menu script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

st -c phpstorm -n phpstorm -e sh -c "storm" & disown
sleep 5; kill $!;
```

This is my helper script called storm:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$(find ~/www -type d | fzf )

[ -z $result ] && exit
nohup phpstorm $result >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I have to kill the suckless terminal session after phpstorm started otherwise the window with terminal after fzf selection remains open and I have to close it manually.
PhpStorm, on the other hand, operates differently than vscode or sublime as it starts with jvm. And even if I do `phpstorm dir &` it keeps throwing java output into the log. I can't make it start in a background properly, does any one know how this should be done in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to achieve results with the following two scripts

`fzfmenu` script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

st -c fzfmenu -n fzfmenu -g "100x12" -e sh -c "storm" & disown
```

`storm` script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

result=$(find ~/www -type d | fzf)

[ -z $result ] && exit

(nohup phpstorm $result >/dev/null 2>&1 &)

pkill -f fzfmenu
```